# PHP and title tag

Tags: php, title

I have already tried searching on the web but I didn't find the solution.

How can I add a 'title' tag with spaces on php code?

I have this:

```
echo "<li id='".$folder.'/'.$entry."' title=".$entry.">".$entry."</li>
```

In this example the variable $entry = "Test one two three", but when my mouse is over div, it only display me "one", he stop on first space.

What can I do to display all title?

Regards.

Comment: this is not related to php... please provide exact html output...

Comment: Your `title=".$entry."` is missing embedded quotes.

Comment: nevermind with this code It show me a list with one element "Test one two three" (without quotes) but when I'm hover this div, only appear "Test" (without quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the mssing single quotes: Your PHP will output

```
<li id='somefoler'/'Test one two three' title=Test one two three>Test one two three</li>
```

Which is not what you want. Try

```
echo "<li id='$folder/$entry' title='$entry'>$entry</li>";
```

Comment: Yep! thanks you, I solved it with (title=' "$entry" ')